# Vue js/Javascript Objects.assign() not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I need to concatenate two objects in Vue/Javascript and order the resulting one by date field but I'm getting empty results using `Object.assign()`.

I've tried other methods searching on StackOverflow but nothing has worked as expected. Mostly I get empty results

```js
methods: {
        getAllMessages: function () {
            // console.log(this.myID);
            let distinct = '';

            firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages').where('memberID', '==', `${this.myID}`)
                .orderBy('date').onSnapshot(res => {

                    let members = [];
                    res.forEach(doc => {
                        members.push(doc.data().uid);
                    });
                    distinct = Array.from(new Set(members));
                    // console.log(distinct);

                    this.getUserToTalk(distinct);
                });
        },
        getMyMessages: function (memberID) {
            let myMessages = [];
            firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages').where('uid', '==', `${this.myID}`).where('memberID', '==', `${memberID}`)
                .orderBy('date').onSnapshot(res => {
                    res.forEach(doc => {
                        myMessages.push(doc.data());
                    });
                });
            // this.myMessages = myMessages;
            return myMessages;
        },
        getMessages: function (memberID) {

            let messages = [];
            firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages').where('uid', '==', `${memberID}`).where('memberID', '==', `${this.myID}`)
                .orderBy('date').onSnapshot(res => {
                    res.forEach(doc => {
                        messages.push(doc.data());
                    });
                });

            // this.memberMessages = messages;
            return messages;

        },
        getUserToTalk: function (memberID) {

            axios.post('http://localhost/backend/getMemberToTalk.php', {
                "token": token,
                "whoToTalkTo": memberID,
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.data != "Error getting user data and tour") {

                    let joinedData = []
                    // console.log(response.data);

                    response.data.forEach(res => {
                        
                        let id = res.memberID;

                        let messages = this.getMessages(id);
                        // console.log(messages);

                        let myMessages = this.getMyMessages(id);
                        // console.log(myMessages);

                        // if I use below assignment I can get the messages, but I need to concat them.
                        // so, if I use let conversation = Object.assign({}, messages, myMessages); 
                        // or let conversation =  { ...messages, ...myMessages }
                        // the result is always empty.

                        let talk1 = Object.assign(messages);
                        let talk2 = Object.assign(myMessages);
                        console.log(talk, talkmy);
                        
                        let data = {
                            memberID: res.memberID,
                            memberProfileImg: res.memberProfileImg,
                            memberName: res.memberName,
                            memberLastname: res.memberLastname,
                            memberCity: res.memberCity,
                            memberState: res.memberState,
                            memberMessages: messages,
                            myMessages: myMessages,
                            // messages: conversation
                        }

                        joinedData.push(data);
                    });
                    // console.log(joinedData);

                    this.memberData = joinedData;
                    // console.log(this.memberData);
                } else {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
}
```

[image]

These are the full objects and in the example below I need to add the object from `messages.js:140` as a "third index" in `messages.js:137` resulting in

`0:{...}`

`1:{...}`

`2:{...}`

and then

`3:{...}`

[image]

Comment: are `messages` and `myMessages` messages objects or arrays?

Comment: I'm getting objects in console.log using `typeof()`

Comment: @Greedo They're empty arrays with an `__ob__` property.

Comment: As they are observers you need to use a function to merge observers (like `merge` in rxjs)

Comment: I updated my script with the main object (data) that I'm using to display user's infos in html with a `v-for`. In `memberMessages` and in `myMessages` inside `data` `console.log(joinedData);` says I have arrays but merging/concatenating them also results in empty data

Comment: `typeof arr` gives `object` always for arrays, you should use `Array.isArray(arr)` for that purpose. To concatenate arrays use `newArr = arr1.concat(arr2)` or `newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2]`

Comment: Hi @OrkhanAlikhanov. I've tried `concat()` too but I get the same empty result. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Ah you have asynchronous code

Comment: Well noted. Would you help me to fix it? I'm trying but had no success until now.